# How to apply Dynamic Programming in SPOJ Feynman?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, divide-and-conquer

I was solving this problem -> http://www.spoj.com/problems/SAMER08F/ (A very simple problem) ... Got AC at my first go... My solution was like this (pretty straight-forward) :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int n;
scanf("%d",&n);
    while(n!=0)
    {
    printf("%d",((n)*(n+1)*((2*n)+1))/6);
    printf("\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I was going through this list http://ahmed-aly.com/Category.jsp?ID=33 and I found Feynman listed as a DP problem... I am a beginer in DP and cannot figure out how can this problem consists of sub-problems. Any help or hint in finding the recurrence relations will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a silly DP. 
 What you are doing here is   [image: formula] right?
Instead what you could do is create an array to hold the sum of squares (Let's call it sumSquares). Now, this is how you would fill the array:

1. sumSquares[0] = 0; (The base case, sum of the squares of the first
   zero elements is zero).
2. sumSquares[i] = sumSquares[i - 1] + [image: formula] (Sum of squares
   of *i* elements is the sum of squares of *(i - 1)* elements + square of the *ith*
   element)

And that's it! You iterate till n, and you have your answer stored at sumSquares[n] !

Comment: This answer doesn't make it clear *why* you can just add i^2 to the previous answer to get the new answer.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Oh I am sorry, any suggestions on how to make it *clear* ?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know why the formula you give works -- at this stage it's a mystery to me.  I would try to make a DP based on the fact that every sub-square of an i*i square is either one of the sumSquares[i-1] sub-squares of an (i-1)*(i-1) square, one of the 2*i-1 possible size-1 squares along the right and bottom edge, or a square created by taking a sub-square of an (i-1)*(i-1) square that touches its right and/or bottom edge, and extending it both right and down by 1.

Answer (score 0):

Just use simple DP. If you observe the pattern you can notice that if You take 1 square it possible to make 64 square. if you take 2 size square it is possible to make (8-1) = 7*7 = 49 size square . 
so you can follow -> (8*8) + (7*7) + ........+(1*1)

```
int feyn[1000];
 long long Feynman(long long x)
 {
if(x==1)return 1 ;

feyn[x]= (x*x)+Feynman(x-1);

return feyn[x];

 }
```